# Chrome Extension, Jquery ajax failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying  to write myself a chrome extension, and I have the following lines in it that seem to be failing:

```
fk_url = "http://www.flipkart.com/search-books?query=" + search + "algorithms&from=all";
$.get(fk_url);
```

And, when my extension is run, it gives me this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.flipkart.com/search-books?query=algorithmsalgorithms&from=all. Origin chrome-extension://cpepfejkgdnhemablbikonijfjnjmnha is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I'm totally lost as to how I can fix this. Any help? (The website I'm trying to connect to does not offer an API)

Comment: why the downvotes? It seems a legitimate n00b question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `manifest.json` file should have the domain you're looking to use in the permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://*.flipkart.com/"
]
```

Comment: Can you post your entire `manifest.json` file then? It'd help to know how to debug this issue.

Comment: I had an error in my JS. Thanks for helping, I got it correct.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't offer an API, you're pretty much out of luck with a Chrome extension, I'm afraid. You can't just AJAX-request any resources from any domain (unless they allow you access: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control).

For more details, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: You can get around this issue by asking for domain permissions in a Chrome extension.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I'm seeing that now at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html ... so, that requires no configuration on the remote server? Cool. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. As far as the remote server knows, you're performing the XHR request *from* that domain.